# iOS Crash reports: Random objects receiving the wrong selector

Tags: iphone, ios, debugging, crash, crash-reports

I recently set up my app with HockeyApp to track crash reports. I've received many useful reports which I've used to fix bugs. However, I am getting a bunch of crash repots that give very strange explanations for what is causing the crash. See this one for example:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_NSFaultingMutableSet alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f2cd490'
```

Now, I do have a number of places in the app where I have `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:`, but I never call it from an `NSMutableSet`. There are a number of similar kinds of crashes, where the selector is not at all affiliated with the object that is supposedly calling it. What would explain these kinds of crashes, and how can I go about fixing them?

---

EDIT:

First, as I explained in the comments to some of the answers, I'm using ARC. Also, here are some other examples, to give a sense of what is happening across the app:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteMutableAttributedString intValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ed29a90'


*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSMallocBlock__ myOwnInternalMethod]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1edcf440'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical symptom of premature deallocation of an object. Check your memory management code and pay attention to reference counts (track when/how many times `retain`, `copy`, `mutableCopy`, `release` and `autorelease` are called).

Comment: I'm using ARC, so I'm not manually releasing or autoreleasing anything.

Comment: @Jason ARC ain't magic. You can still get it wrong. In this case, check if you have a `weak` property where you should have a `strong` or the alike.

Comment: What should I be looking for as I'm searching for this? I am not getting any zombie crashes so I don't think that objects are being released earlier than they need to be.

Answer (score 1):

this is more than likely a case of an object that has been released, is deleted and the memory is reused by another object

Answer (score 0):

are you using ARC? If not, most of this crashes occure when you release (or autorelease) an Object and not setting all references to this Object (for example delegates) to nil afterwards.

I choose a ScrollView as Example.

```
@interface MyExampleController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIScrollView *scrollView;

@end


@implementation MyExampleController

- (UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (!_scrollView) {
        _scrollView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [_scrollView setDelegate:self];
    }
    return _scrollView;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    // Normaly the ScrollView should die the same time the Controller does
    // but sometimes another object might hold a reference
    // so the delegate has to be set to nil to prevent the ScrollView to call an Object no longer exist
    [_scrollView setDelegate:nil];
}

@end
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using ARC. But some of the libraries I'm using (e.g. ASIHTTPRequest) are not ARC-friendly, so I'm compiling those files without ARC.

Comment: Than i assume most of your crashes happen because you forgot to set a delegate-property to nil while your delegate-object is dealloced. In the example of yours it is a `UIAlertView`. You present the alertview but the delegate is deallocated before the alertview is dismissed.

Comment: So at what point would I set the delegate to nil? In `dealloc`, should I set `self = nil;`?

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with H2CO3, Daij-Djan and Jonathan Cichon, that the reason probably is that a message is sent to a deallocated object.
One reason this can happen is if you have a thread without an autorelease pool set up, and you create an autorelease object. In this case it is not retained since no autorelease pool exists, and deallocated immediately after allocation. So, if you have multithreaded code, check if all threads have an `@autoreleasepool{...}` block that covers more or less the whole thread code.